# read the values from the array in which the arrays are

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I change the currentHistoryIndex in option in select as click, e.g. 5 to react developers tools I have curentHistoryIndex: 5

```
state= {
history: [[{ "Name": "name", "Description": "xxx", "X": 18.6355611, "Y": 53.0331258 }], [{ "Name": "name1", "Description": "xxx", "X": 18.6355611, "Y": 53.0331258 }, { "Name": "name3", "Description": "xxxx", "X": 18.6355611, "Y": 53.0331258 }, { "Name": "name4", "Description": "xxx", "X": 18.6355611, "Y": 53.0331258 }, { "Name": "namee", "Description": "xxx", "X": 18.6355611, "Y": 53.0331258 }]],
}
currentHistoryIndex:0
```

I have a problem displaying this data

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.history[this.state.currentHistoryIndex].length; i++) {
        var obj = this.state.history[i][i];
        let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
        new mapboxgl.Marker()
          .setLngLat(myLatlng)
          .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
            .setHTML('<h3>' + obj.Name + '</h3><p>' + obj.Description + '</p>'
            ))
          .addTo(map);
      }
```

Comment: But `this.state.history[i][i]` may be wrong

Comment: Where are you storing this data? What's wrong with just storing an array of objects?

Comment: when in the table I have tables where the length is 2/3 it works, but when 4+, an error pops up TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined, or TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined